# How to play against AD Nidalee top lane as Riven?

Tags: league-of-legends

I always seem to have a problem playing against AD Nidalee as Riven. Is there any certain way to play against her?

Answer (score 3):

AD Nidalee excels at her laning phase, however, she falls behind quite significantly during mid/late game. If you notice that the Nidalee is equally or more skilled than you are, you should play passive, since it is highly unlikely that you can trade with her efficiently. Do not go for last hits if the risk is too high.

Once you hit mid/late-game, you should be ahead, even though you might be behind her in CS, due to the fact that Riven brings a lot more to teamfights than AD Nidalee.

Wish you the best of luck versus them Nidalees!

Answer (score 1):

Start Cloth Armor + 5 pots, also armor yellow runes. Build Cloth Armor into Wriggle's Lantern --> Phage, and maybe throw a Doran's Blade in there if you just have the money for it.

Start with E (Valor) to negate a bit of her annoying early game harass.

Answer (score 1):

Start 5 pots + cloth armor and start with wriggles for sustain and a little bit of armor.
Nid will harass you a lot early game but as is get late in the game you will start to dominate her.

Answer (score 1):

Nidalee can be a problematic match up for many top lane bruisers, but as Riven you have an advantage most bruisers do not. Riven's extreme mobility and lack of resource management give her an edge in this match up. Nidalee dominates the laning phase in most match ups by auto attack spamming from a brush. By placing a ward in the brush you will deny her the ability to drop creep aggro by running back into the brush. Although she will receive a movement speed buff when entering the brush Riven can easily close the gap and harass Nidalee with Q and E then catching her with a W and a series of auto attacks.